# How do I add inputs together from more than 1 input in Python

Tags: python

I want to input something like "g 1 2 3" repeatedly and have the numbers add to a variable each time I enter them. I made a test program however the output is wrong e.g. if I enter "g 1 2 3" 3 times I would expect my variable to print "3" but it prints "0". What is wrong with my code?

```
AddTot = int(0)
NameMarks = input("Please input your name followed by your marks seperated by spaces ")
NameMSplit = NameMarks.split()
while NameMarks != 'Q':
    Name1 = int(NameMSplit[1])
    Name2 = int(NameMSplit[2])
    Name3 = int(NameMSplit[3])
    AddTot + Name1
    NameMarks = input("Please input your name followed by your marks seperated by spaces ")
print(AddTot)
```

Answer (score 1):

`AddTot + Name1` does *not* modify `AddTot`, as in the result won't be stored anywhere. Replace it with

```
AddTot += Name1 # same as `AddTot = AddTot + Name1`
```

That said, your program only uses the first input. To fix that, move `NameMSplit = NameMarks.split()` within the loop body:

```
AddTot = int(0)
NameMarks = input("Please input your name followed by your marks seperated by spaces ")
while NameMarks != 'Q':
    NameMSplit = NameMarks.split() # here
    Name1 = int(NameMSplit[1])
    Name2 = int(NameMSplit[2])
    Name3 = int(NameMSplit[3])
    AddTot += Name1
    NameMarks = input("Please input your name followed by your marks seperated by spaces ")
print(AddTot)
```

As for further improvements, you can shorten your code a little:

```
AddTot = 0 # or int() without argument
say = "Please input your name followed by your marks seperated by spaces "
NameMarks = input(say)
while NameMarks != 'Q':
    marks = [int(x) for x in NameMarks.split()[1:]]
    AddTot += marks[0]
    NameMarks = input(say)

print(AddTot)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, for some reason if i do something like
"g 100 2 3"
"g 1 2 3"
"g 1 2 3"

the output is 300